# how to add a symbol into datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to implement load and go sic assembler, I have used 3 gridviews one stores the read pgm , menoic values and other an empty gridview which would act as symbole table I am having trouble while trying to enter new value gridview that should hold symbole and its address,here is my code.

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
  static System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=D:/ASSEMBLER.mdb");
        string start_address;
        int k = 0;
        string value;
        int ma;
        int nxt_add = 0;
        string opcode;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            grid1();
            grid2();
            grid3();
        }

        private void grid1()
        {

        //  var ss = new List<string> { "BYTE", "RESW", "RESB", "WORD" };
        try
        {
            //   InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapReport = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select Adress as [address], opcode as [Symbol],operand as [opco],op as [operand],ooo as[obj] from read_pgm" + "'", con1);
            adapReport.Fill(ds, "read_pgm");
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "read_pgm";


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

            }
            Int16 b = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            //start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            // MessageBox.Show(add + " in second form");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con1.Close();
        }


    }
    private void grid2()
    {


        con1.Open();
        try
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapReport = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select SYMBOLE as [Symbol],ADDRESS as [ADDRESS] from SYMBOL_TABLE" + "'", con1);
            adapReport.Fill(ds1, "SYMBOL_TABLE");
            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds1;
            dataGridView2.DataMember = "SYMBOL_TABLE";


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView2.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

            }
            //Int16 b = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            //start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            // MessageBox.Show(add + " in second form");

            con1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }


    }
    private void grid3()
    {



        try
        {
            con1.Open();
            // InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapReport = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select opcode as [opcode],val as [value] from Mnemoni" + "'", con1);
            adapReport.Fill(ds2, "Mnemoni");
            dataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView3.DataSource = ds2;
            dataGridView3.DataMember = "Mnemoni";


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView3.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

            }
            //Int16 b = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            //start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            // MessageBox.Show(add + " in second form");

            con1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }


    }


    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





        cal(dataGridView1, dataGridView2, dataGridView3);

    }
    private void add()
    {

        try
        {
            con1.Open();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand top = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(
    "INSERT INTO SYMBOL_TABLE (" +
            "SYMBOLE,ADDRESS" +
        ") VALUES (?,?)", con1);

            top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", opcode);
            top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "xxxx");
            top.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con1.Close();
            grid2();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void cal(DataGridView dataGridView1, DataGridView dataGridView2, DataGridView dataGridView3)
    {

        start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);
        MessageBox.Show("this is start adder" + start_address);

        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            opcode = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            string operand = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            string op = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            MessageBox.Show(opcode);
            string cv = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(cv);
            // int nxt_add =Convert.ToInt16(cv);
            nxt_add = nxt_add + 3;
            string address = nxt_add.ToString("X");
            dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Value = address;

            // MessageBox.Show(operand);
            //MessageBox.Show(op);
            if (opcode != null && opcode != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inside opcode loop");

                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    try
                    {
                        if (dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == opcode)
                        {
                            ma = j;
                            string m = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show("value of m" + m);
                            dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = m;
                            MessageBox.Show("if condition satisified block of opcode and it is exiting now ");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("opcode value is " + opcode);
                        int a = dataGridView2.NewRowIndex;

                        dataGridView2.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value = opcode;
                        dataGridView2.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value = "xxxx";
                        // ma = k;
                        // k++;

                        MessageBox.Show("exiting catch block of opcode");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; y++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("content of symbole table");
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
            if (operand != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inside the operan loop");
                for (int kj = 0; kj < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; kj++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (dataGridView3.Rows[kj].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == operand)
                        {
                            value = dataGridView3.Rows[kj].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show(value);
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // MessageBox.Show("invalid operand");
                            continue;
                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("inside the catch block of operand loop  ");
                        //  MessageBox.Show(e.Message+e.InnerException);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (op != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("in the op loop");
                if (op == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("op is empty space ****");
                }
                int[] num = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
                if (op.Contains(Convert.ToString(num)))
                {

                }
                int f = dataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.X;
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    try
                    {
                        if (dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == opcode)
                        {
                            ma = j;
                            string m = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show("value of m" + m);
                            dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = m;
                            MessageBox.Show("if condition satisified block of opcode and it is exiting now ");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("opcode value is " + opcode);
                        int a = dataGridView2.NewRowIndex;

                        dataGridView2.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value = opcode;
                        dataGridView2.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value = "xxxx";
                        // ma = k;
                        // k++;

                        MessageBox.Show("exiting catch block of opcode");
                        break;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("op value is  " + op);
                    try
                    {
                        int b = dataGridView2.NewRowIndex;
                        dataGridView2.Rows[b].Cells[0].Value = op;
                        dataGridView2.Rows[b].Cells[1].Value = "xxxx";

                    }
                    catch (Exception v)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(v.Message);
                    }
                    //  dataGridView2.BeginEdit(true);
                    // dataGridView2.EndEdit();
                    MessageBox.Show("exiting op loop");
                }
                MessageBox.Show("value of i is " + i);
                for (int o = 0; o < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; o++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[o].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[o].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                }


            }

        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Besides the methods being __way__ to long, skimming over the code I see __no explanation or hint just what your question is__. _I am having trouble_ Is just as insufficient as a problem description as _doesn't work_ .. Please help us helping you by making clear just what your problem might be! Also: __Always tag the platform__ you're  targetting; as you mention DataGridView I __assume__ winforms?

Comment: Yes it's windows forms

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for my question with few modification I have completed simple sic load and go assembler. my code as follows                             `
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string opcode;
        string labelz;
        string operand;
        string m;
        string fg;
        string d;
        int a = 0;
        string value;
        static System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=D:/ASSEMBLER.mdb");
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            grid1();
            grid2();
            grid3();

```
    }
    private void grid1()
    {
        try
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapReport = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select Adress as [address], opcode as [Symbol],operand as [opco],op as [operand],ooo as[obj] from read_pgm" + "'", con1);
            adapReport.Fill(ds, "read_pgm");
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "read_pgm";


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

            }
            Int16 b = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            //start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            // MessageBox.Show(add + " in second form");

            con1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }


    }
    private void grid2()
    {


        con1.Open();
        try
        {

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapReport = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select SYMBOLE as [Symbol],ADDRESS as [ADDRESS] from SYMBOL_TABLE" + "'", con1);
            adapReport.Fill(ds1, "SYMBOL_TABLE");
            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds1;
            dataGridView2.DataMember = "SYMBOL_TABLE";


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView2.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

            }
            //Int16 b = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            //start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            // MessageBox.Show(add + " in second form");

            con1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }

        //con1.Close();
    }
    private void grid3()
    {


        con1.Open();
        try
        {

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapReport = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select opcode as [opcode],val as [value] from Mnemoni" + "'", con1);
            adapReport.Fill(ds2, "Mnemoni");
            dataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView3.DataSource = ds2;
            dataGridView3.DataMember = "Mnemoni";


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView3.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

            }
            //Int16 b = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            //start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);

            // MessageBox.Show(add + " in second form");

            con1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }


    }##
```

1. Heading

   ## #

   ```
   private void cal(DataGridView dataGridView1, DataGridView dataGridView2, DataGridView dataGridView3)
   {

       string start_address = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value);


       ///   MessageBox.Show("this is start adder" + start_address);
       for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
       {
           labelz = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
           opcode = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
           operand = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
           string objcod = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);

           a = a + Convert.ToInt16(3);
           // start_address = Convert.ToString(a);

           string s = a.ToString("X");
           string bv = a.ToString();

           if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() != "END")
           {
               if (bv.Length == 2)
               {
                   string tr = start_address.Remove(1, 2);
                   dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Value = tr + s;
               }

               else if (bv.Length < 2)
               {
                   string tr = start_address.Remove(2, 1);
                   dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Value = tr + s;
               }
           }
           d = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

           if (labelz != null && labelz != "")
           {
               MessageBox.Show("label is" + labelz + " value is" + d);
               im(labelz, d);
               grid2();
           }
           if (opcode != null)
           {
               for (int kj = 0; kj < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; kj++)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       if (dataGridView3.Rows[kj].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == opcode)
                       {
                           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dataGridView3.Rows[kj].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                           value = dataGridView3.Rows[kj].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {
                       string qw = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                       if (qw.Length == 4)
                       {
                           value = "00" + qw;
                           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = value;
                       }
                       if (qw.Length == 1)
                       {
                           value = "00000" + qw;
                           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = value;
                       }
                       if (qw.Length == 2)
                       {
                           value = "0000" + qw;
                           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = value;
                       }
                       if (qw.Length == 3)
                       {
                           value = "000" + qw;
                           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = value;
                       }
                   }
               }

               if (operand != ""&& opcode != "WORD" | opcode != "RESW")
               {


                   try
                   {
                       for (int jm = 0; jm < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; jm++)
                       {

                           //break;

                           if (dataGridView2.Rows[jm].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == operand)
                           {


                               for (int hj = 0; hj < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; hj++)
                               {
                                   if (dataGridView1.Rows[hj].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == operand)
                                   {

                                       m = dataGridView1.Rows[hj].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                                       MessageBox.Show("symbole" + operand + " is already in symbol table" + "with address" + m);
                                       cv(operand,m);
                                       grid2();
                                       break;
                                   }
                                  /* else
                                   {
                                       cv(operand,"XXXX");
                                       grid2();
                                   }*/
                               }


                           }
                       }

                   }
                   catch (NullReferenceException e)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("symbol" + operand + "is not present in symbol table & entered with value" + "xxxx");
                       cv(operand, "XXXX");
                       grid2();
                       //break;
                   }
               }

               if (operand == "")
               {
                   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = value + "0000";
               }
           }

           MessageBox.Show("object code is" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

           if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "")
           {
               for (int jh = 0; jh < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; jh++)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       if (dataGridView2.Rows[jh].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == operand)
                       {

                           fg = dataGridView2.Rows[jh].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = value + fg;
                           MessageBox.Show(operand);
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   catch (NullReferenceException v)
                   {
                       break;

                   }

               }
           }

           for (int mi = 1; mi < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; mi++)
           {
               if (dataGridView1.Rows[mi].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length == 3)
               {
                   string sd = dataGridView1.Rows[mi].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                   sd = sd.Insert(1, "0");
                   dataGridView1.Rows[mi].Cells[0].Value = sd;
               }
               try
               {
                   string kj = dataGridView1.Rows[mi].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                   //  MessageBox.Show("kj length is" + kj.Length);

                   if (kj.Length < 6)
                   {
                       for (int re = 0; re < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; re++)
                       {
                           if (dataGridView2.Rows[re].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[mi].Cells[3].Value.ToString())
                           {
                               string vv = dataGridView2.Rows[re].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                               dataGridView1.Rows[mi].Cells[4].Value = kj + vv;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (NullReferenceException v)
               {

               }
           }
       }
   }

   private static void im(string lab, string d)
   {

       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=D:/ASSEMBLER.mdb");
       try
       {
           con1.Open();

           System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand top = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(
   "INSERT INTO SYMBOL_TABLE (" +
           "SYMBOLE,ADDRESS" +
       ") VALUES (?,?)", con1);

           top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", lab);
           top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", d);
           //  top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", mcs[2]);
           top.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con1.Close();

       }


       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
   public static void cv(string a, string b)
   {

       try
       {
           con1.Open();
           System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand top1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE SYMBOL_TABLE SET[ADDRESS] = ? where SYMBOLE = ?", con1);
           top1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", a);
           top1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", b);

           top1.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con1.Close();

       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
       }
   }
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       cal(dataGridView1, dataGridView2, dataGridView3);

   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.Close();
   }
   ```

   }
   }

   `